# Unable to get Fragment Manager from RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragmentmanager

I'm attempting to transit out of a recycler view into a target fragment, but it seems like I can't get the fragment manager to do so.  When I try to build, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
```

The code below is what's causing the error, specifically the line with `getSupportManager()`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final Course course = courses.get(i);
    if (course != null)
    {
        viewHolder.course = course;
        viewHolder.tvLine1.setText(course.getName());
        viewHolder.tvLine2.setText(course.getCourse_code());
        viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                CourseViewFragment viewFragment = new CourseViewFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("CourseID", course.getId());
                args.putString("CourseName", course.getName());
                args.putString("CourseCode", course.getCourse_code());
                args.putString("StartAt", course.getStart_at());
                args.putString("EndAt", course.getEnd_at());
                viewFragment.setArguments(args);
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .add(android.R.id.content, viewFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show where you are calling this Adapter

Comment: Your context variable is null. Are setting it up somewhere in adapter?

Comment: in fragment use getActivity instead of context

Comment: you have to pass context to adapter from your fragment or activity

Comment: please upload the complete code of Adapter class for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your adapter. It seems that the context is null when you click the item.

Normally it is caused by **destroyed Activities**. Here's one scenario:

1. The adapter receive the context via constructor or setter, and keep the reference to the activity.
2. The Activity is destroyed for some reason (user action, low memory, etc.)
3. The context that the adapter has becomes **null**
4. You get NPE.

So please check where you call adapter. Maybe the answer is in there.